# C++ atomic on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, atomic, compare-and-swap

I have the next isolated test fragment inside an iOS project:

```
/// ...
std::atomic_bool ab;
ab.store(true);
bool expected = false;
while (!ab.compare_exchange_weak(expected, true));
assert(0);
// ...
```

Provided that `ab` is not modified by other threads, I expected, that the loop would be infinite, but after executing I found out that the `assert` is failing. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compare_exchange_weak` changes the first parameter to what was actually there. So after the first iteration of the loop expected has been changed to `true`. This then is fed back into the loop where the [`compare_exchange_weak`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) succeeds and proceeds to fail the assertion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, accurate note

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is touching `ab` and nothing is touching `expected`, (and no other threads are running that could hit this area's memory,) then that assert should not fire off...

unless the compiler is helping you by eliminating dead code i.e. the `while` loop does nothing so don't include it and therefore you hit the assert.  Check your assembler output to be sure or add a global varaible counter to the loop so that the compiler won't kill this dead code for you.